# Getting inheritance issues when trying to compile

Tags: stack, class-hierarchy

I have a class called stackTester that is trying to inherit from another class stackofChars. The methods defined in stackofChars that I am trying to use in stackTester are all virtual, but when I try to use them in stackTester, I get an error

> request for member which is of non-class type

Here is my stackofChars.h file:

```
#define STACK_OF_CHARS_H
#include "node.h"

class stackofChars
{
    private:
    node* m_top;
    
    public:
    //constructor for the stack, takes in no paramaters
    stackofChars();
    
    //copy constructor, takes in a referance to the original stack
    stackofChars(const stackofChars& orig);
    
    //destructor for the stack, no parameters
    ~stackofChars();
    
    //destructor for the copy, takes in a referance to the copy
    void operator=(const stackofChars& rhs);
    
    //pushes the stack back and creates a new node at the stop, takes in an entry, returns nothing
    virtual void push(char entry);
    
    //deletes the top entry and pushes the stack up, takes in nothing, returns nothing
    virtual void pop();

    //peeks at the top entry, takes in nothing, returns a char, const because nothing is changed
    virtual char peek() const;
    
    //checks if the stack is empty, takes in no parameters, returns nothing, const because nothing is changed
    virtual bool isEmpty() const;
};
#endif
```

Here is my stackTester.h file:

```
#ifndef STACK_TESTER_H
#define STACK_TESTER_H
#include "stackofChars.h"

class stackTester : public stackofChars
{   
    public: 

    stackTester();

    //This will call all your test methods
    void runTests();
     
    private:

    //Creates an empty stack and verifies isEmpty() returns true
    void test1();

    //Creates an empty stack pushes 1 value, verifies isEmpty() returns false
    void test2();

    //Creates an empty stack, then pushes once, pops once, and verifies isEmpty returns true
    void test3();

    //more test methods as needed
};
#endif
```

If needed, here is my stackTester.cpp file:

```
#include "stackTester.h"
#include "stackofChars.h"
#include <iostream>

void stackTester::test1()
{
    stackofChars test();
    std::cout << "Test#1: Newly created stack is empty: ";
    if(test.isEmpty() == true)
    {
        std::cout << "Pass\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Fail\n";
    }
}

void stackTester::test2()
{
    stackofChars test();
    test.push(???);
    std::cout << "Test#2: Push on empty stack makes it non-empty: ";
    if(test.isEmpty() == true)
    {
        std::cout << "Pass\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Fail\n";
    }
}

void stackTester::test3()
{
    stackofChars test();
    test.push(???);
    test.pop();
    std::cout << "Test#3: Popping all elements makes stack empty: ";
    if(test.isEmpty() == true)
    {
        std::cout << "Pass\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Fail\n";
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

`stackofChars test();` is wrong.The right way to declare a class object should be: `stackofChars test;` or `stackofChars test{};`
There is an explanation here [enter link description here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#empty-parens-in-object-decl)